# CSS close dropdown menu after click

Tags: javascript, css, html, drop-down-menu

I've created a dropdown menu in css with first and second level.

```css
#horizzontalMenu {
  width: 770px;
  height: 570px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
#horizzontalMenu,
#horizzontalMenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#horizzontalMenu {
  height: 41px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#horizzontalMenu ul {
  left: -9999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  width: auto;
}
#horizzontalMenu ul ul {
  left: -9999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
}
#horizzontalMenu li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
#horizzontalMenu li a {
  background: #c1c1bf;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#horizzontalMenu > li > a {
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#horizzontalMenu li a.fly {
  background: #c1c1bf url(../images/arrow.gif) no-repeat right center;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
#horizzontalMenu ul li {
  margin: 0;
}
#horizzontalMenu ul li a {
  width: 120px;
}
#horizzontalMenu ul li a.fly {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#horizzontalMenu li:hover > a {
  background-color: #858180;
  color: #fff;
}
#horizzontalMenu li a:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}
#horizzontalMenu li a:active + ul.dd,
#horizzontalMenu li a:focus + ul.dd,
#horizzontalMenu li ul.dd:hover {
  left: 0;
}
#horizzontalMenu ul.dd li a:active + ul,
#horizzontalMenu ul.dd li a:focus + ul,
#horizzontalMenu ul.dd li ul:hover {
  left: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="horizzontalMenu" />
  <li class='Documenti'>
    <a class="fly" href="#">Document</a>
    <ul class="dd">
      <li id="menu_documentiEmessi">
        <a class="fly" href="#">Documenti emessi</a>
        <ul>
          <li id="menu_docFattOut"><a>Fatture</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu_fatturaPA"><a>Fatture PA (beta)</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu_preventivi"><a>Preventivi</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu_ddt"><a>DDT</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu_docProfOut" class='last-child'><a>Proforma</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_documentiRicevuti">
        <a class="fly" href="#">Documenti ricevuti</a>
        <ul>
          <li id="menu_docFattIn"><a>Fatture</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu_docProfIn"><a>Proforma</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_docGenerici"><a>Documenti generici</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_docTributi"><a>Tributi</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_primanota"><a>Prima nota</a>
      </li>
      <li class='separator'></li>
      <li id="menu_crediti"><a>Crediti</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_debiti" class='last-child'><a>Debiti</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to close first or second level after mouse click. Is it possible?
I want to close menu only when mouse click on `li` element without opening a second level.

Can you help me?

Carlo

Comment: Please add the code from your JSFiddle to the question. If jsfiddle goes down your question is unanswerable.

Comment: But it was not necessary delete link to JSFiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use only CSS, but you have to change button to checkbox and open menu written as :checked+ul

```
<ul id="horizzontalMenu"/>
    <li class='Documenti'   >
        <label class="fly" for="fly-checkbox">Document</label><input type="checkbox" id="fly-checkbox" />
        <ul class="dd">
            <li id="menu_documentiEmessi">
...
```

---

```
#horizzontalMenu li label.fly {
    background:#c1c1bf url(../images/arrow.gif) no-repeat right center;
    padding:8px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -o-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
}

#fly-checkbox {
    display:none;
}

#fly-checkbox:checked+ul.dd,
#fly-checkbox:checked+ul.dd:hover {
    left:0;
}

#fly-checkbox:checked+ul,
#fly-checkbox:checked+ul:hover {
    left:140px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ek2bdgz/6/